# Hacker Redirect my site to there site by putting @ and then there domain name

Tags: reactjs, routes

My project is in reactjs
domain is https://tomi.com
But what hacker is doing just redirecting my user to there site by just putting

https://tomi.com@nzqbjldct180zzvlv42vx0fh288ywn.burpcollaborator.net/

this url he just used my domain tomi.com and then after that @ and there domain name if i put any other domain name after @ it will redirect me there so is there any solution to resolve this

i was using redirection in my app js also i have removed that but not works

Comment: You can do some research on Open redirect attach. here's a [link](https://learn.snyk.io/lesson/open-redirect/) but there are plenty of material online available on this subject too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.